# Display multiple arrays in a html table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display multiple arrays into a table so that each value is on a separate line within the table.

This is my current setup:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

 <tr>
   <td><? echo $res['partnumber']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $res['partdescription']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $res['partprice']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $res['partquantity']; ?></td>

<?php
    }

?>
```

Which displays the following:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmc6q.png)

[image]

instead i need it to display each value on a separate line

I tried the following but it duplicates its value over and over again.

```
<? foreach ($res as $row) : ?>
 <tr>
   <td><? echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $row['partdescription']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $row['partprice']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $row['partquantity']; ?></td>
 </tr>
 <? endforeach; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: looks like your values are concatenated strings. Is `"asdf, aasdfas, asdf"` single database value?

Comment: $partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
 $partnumberarray = implode( ", ", $partnumber);

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, make sure to secure `$id` (ex. `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];`) before putting it into your query string.

then try:

```
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
 <tr>
   <td><? echo $res['partnumber']; ?></td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td><? echo $res['partdescription']; ?></td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td><? echo $res['partprice']; ?></td>
 </tr><tr>
   <td><? echo $res['partquantity']; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need new line for each column must simply add  new `tr` for each `td`

Try this:

```
<? foreach ($res as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $row['partdescription']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $row['partprice']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><? echo $row['partquantity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
 <? endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the change in the starting curly braces, and that i removed the endforeach you used, and the table tags...

Now you can make use of this in your for each loop.

```
 <table>
 <? foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td><? echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['partdescription']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['partprice']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['partquantity']; ?></td>
    </tr>
 <? 
     }
 ?>
 </table>
```

I think this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

This is what i'm getting with your code:
(i'll fix the security issue after i get this working, thank you)

```
    <?php

    $id = $_GET['id'];


    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id=$id");

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>
    <? foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partdescription']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partprice']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partquantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
    <? 
    }

    }

    ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['name'=>'jon', 'age'=>30, 'address'=>'dilly'];
$arr2 = ['name'=>'gita', 'age'=>20, 'address'=>'goha'];
$arr3 = ['name'=>'sita', 'age'=>20, 'address'=>'pune'];

$agroup = array([$arr1, $arr2, $arr3]);
 
?>

<table>
  <?php foreach($agroup as list($a, $b, $c)){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $a['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $b['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $a['age']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $b['age']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['age']; ?></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $a['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $b['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $c['address']; ?></td>
  </tr>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```